# Return type for function/triggers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

So, after finally getting a bit knowledge about triggers and functions in postgresql, I can't seem to find out whats wrong here:

I create a function for a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_totaal_telling()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE totaal_telling
SET telling_getal = (SELECT SUM(pers_salaris) FROM personeel)
RETURNING telling_getal;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Then I create the trigger for it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_totaal_telling
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON personeel
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE upd_totaal_telling();
```

But when I try to insert a value into table, I get this error:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL
>   function upd_totaal_telling() line 3 at SQL statement
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: query has no destination for result data SQL state: 42601
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function upd_totaal_telling() line 3 at SQL
>   statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RETURNING telling_getal` at the end of your `UPDATE` statement is equivalent to having a `SELECT telling_getal FROM ...` query. If you ran it on its own, you'd get a result set as the output of your query.

But a PostgreSQL function - whether it's a trigger function or not - cannot produce a result set that way, only a return value. A bare `SELECT` (or `RETURNING`) does not automatically become the return value of the function. That's what "no destination for result data" means - you are trying to "output" some data, but there is nowhere for that "output" to go.

In this particular case, it seems like your trigger has done its work, and doesn't need to output anything. Since you've defined it to run "after" the target update, it doesn't need to return anything particular, but you do need to return something. To do that, you need to add [a `RETURN` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING); as the [page on trigger functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) says:

> The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER ... is always ignored; it might as well be null.

So the line you need to add at the end of your function, after the update statement not part of it, is quite simply:

```
RETURN NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However when I delete the returning part and try to add a value to trigger the trigger, I get another error: 
ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

Comment: Also, found this ins the manual: A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I thought you could omit the return statement altogether. The correct way to return NULL is, quite simply, `RETURN NULL;` - I will update the answer with a reference.

Comment: Just as I read your reply, I figured it out, hehe. I had to do a collom (;) after the "SET telling_getal = (SELECT SUM(pers_salaris) FROM personeel)" which I hadn't and then followed with RETURN NULL;